# What is the difference between app.usestaticfiles & app.usefileserver for OWIN

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2017, owin

I want to know what is the difference between these two blocks of code for OWIN.

It seems to me that they are doing the same job.

**1.**

```
 string root = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
            var physicalFileSystem = new PhysicalFileSystem(Path.Combine(root, "wwwroot"));
            var options = new FileServerOptions
            {
                RequestPath = PathString.Empty,
                EnableDefaultFiles = true,
                FileSystem = physicalFileSystem
            };
            options.StaticFileOptions.FileSystem = physicalFileSystem;
            options.StaticFileOptions.ServeUnknownFileTypes = false;

            app.UseFileServer(options);
```

**2.**

```
    app.UseStaticFiles("wwwroot");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`IAppBuilder.UseFileserver` combines `UseStaticFiles` `UseDefaultFiles`, but not `UseDirectorybrowser` by default.

That means:

```
app.UseFileServer(enableDirectoryBrowsing: true);
```

enables all of the above, while

```
app.UseFileServer();
```

only enables static files and default files, but not directory browsing.
In reverse that means, that `IAppBuilder.UseStaticFiles` only enables the webserver to serve static files, but does not make any assumptions about default documents or directory browsing.